# Can i use Paint.NET API to embedd it in Winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, paint, paint.net

I'm trying to let the use crop a selected area from picture in my winforms application and thought to embed the Paint.NET and limit its functions. I understand that Paint.NET API is unavailable..
I'll be happy to get recommendation for another tool i can use to crop images in Winforms application.

Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your requirements are fairly simple, you might be able to roll your own image cropper using a PictureBox and a few mouse events. :)

Comment: +1. For a simple crop operation this will be FAR more simple than integrating Paint.NET - or anything else for that matter of fact. System.Drawing namespace already supports all that is needed.

Comment: thanks, the consideration was that if we need to develop the crop, the app will support crop only, but if we integrating another component we might be able to support some other features that will shipped with the component.

Answer (score 0):

What paint.net API? There is no paint.net api for using it from other programs.

Comment: Yep, after googling with no result for Paint.NET api i understood that the API is unavailable. but you might know another tool?

Answer (score 0):

you can try IpLab to see if it meets your needs. see http://code.google.com/p/iplab/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).  They have a [.NET wrapper](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/) for it so it should be usable from C#.